# Bullet: Load/Save collisionshape

Tags: c++, serialization, game-engine, game-physics, bulletphysics

I am trying to prefent looping all triangles and add each one to the btTriangleMesh. (Only loading has to be fast, saving speed can be ignored.)

So what is the fastest method for loading collision data from a file.
How about these two:

1. Saving a Vertex(bt3Vector) & Index(DWORD) array and on loading just
   resize the btTriangleMesh and set the data at once.
2. Using the serializeSingleShape() for saving and for loading
   something like the ReadBulletSample (or init a new btDynamicsWorld,
   read the file with  the BulletWorldImporter, get the collision
   object and cleanup the btDynamicsWorld var)

If there are any other methods, please tell me.
The model geometry has these two buffers:

```
Vertex = vector<float[3]>
Index = vector<DWORD>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used serialization code from bullet. I believe it is already optimized and do no see reason why you should re-invent it.

`bt_col` - is bullet collision object

```
    int maxSerializeBufferSize = 1024*1024*5;
    btDefaultSerializer*    serializer = new btDefaultSerializer(maxSerializeBufferSize);

    serializer->startSerialization();
    bt_col->serializeSingleShape(serializer);
    serializer->finishSerialization();

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    fwrite(serializer->getBufferPointer(),serializer->getCurrentBufferSize(),1, file);
    fclose(file);

    delete serializer;
```

Comment: What class are you using for loading? BulletWorldImporter?

Comment: yes. 

  if(bulletName && strlen(bulletName) > 0){
   btBulletWorldImporter importer;
   importer.loadFile(bulletName);
   block2.bt_col = importer.getCollisionShapeByIndex(0);
  }else{
   block2.bt_col = nullptr;
  }

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would do the following:

- If the collision file is really big then read it in blocks until you get what you want.
- Use a **memory pool** to store the blocks to avoid heap fragmentation when new'ing / deleting.
- Then proceed with the actual collision tests.

If you're trying to save the data you can save them as a struct.

```
struct Triangle
{
  float vertices[9]; // 3x3
  int index;
};
```

If the structs are not of the same size then it'll get a bit more complicated.

```
struct Triangle
{
  int prevOffset; // Offset to the beginning of the previous struct in bytes .. ie. 20 bytes
  int nextOffset; // Offset at the beginning of the next struct
  std::vector<float[3]> Vertices;
  int index;
};
```

Reading:

```
int offset = 0;
char* m_Data; // Pointer to the contents of the file
Triangle *getTriangle(){

   Triangle* tri = (Triangle*)( m_Data+offset );
   offset = tri->Next;
   return tri;

}
```

You write the structs as bytes while storing the offsets.

```
    // Writing the pool
    tri->next = ( (int)tri-(int)m_Data )+tri->Vertices.size()*4+16;
    // For a 32bit system 
    // +12 for the ints (next/prev/id)
    // *4 for the floats
```

It's exactly how memory pools link their chunck headers. Using pointers to the previous and next item so you can **iterate both ways**.

Comment: My question is more about how to actually save collision data to a file. For example my FBX-ModelConverter could easily loop all triangles and create a **btTriangleMesh**, but I have no idea how to save that **btTriangleMesh**. I think I will derive **btStridingMeshInterface** and build a own data provider which is able to save and load data to/from a file.

Comment: Thanks! Really interesting I will give it a try and compare the performance :)